# Parse.com filtering and using custom listview layout on Android

Tags: android, parse-platform, android-parsequeryadapter

I have made an application by usign Parse.com. I retrieve data to listview and spinner with Parse Query Adapter. Everything is cool till here. The problem occured when I try to use a custom layout for listview and spinner. I made the layouts but I couldnt find how to assign that layout to Parse Query Adapter. Another issue is I couldnt find a way to filter Parse Query Adapter for search feature. Is there any solution for these or any other ideas?

I also tried to retrieve all data with normal parse.com query to ArrayList and use regular ArrayAdapter but that also didnt work. I dont know why but I couldnt make spinner data select. It shows data as dropdown but none are selectable.

Comment: https://github.com/ParsePlatform/OfflineTodos/blob/master/android/src/com/parse/offlinetodos/TodoListActivity.java  check out the adapter code in the sample and adopt it for your projs adapters/lists.

Comment: @RobertRowntree That works great for using custom layout. I have tried it before but that wasnt work. I probably missed something before then. Thank you. That solved one part of my problem. Do you have any idea for adding search feature to listview?